# Searching Dictionary in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working on my first project with API's and I am having trouble accessing the data. I am working off an example that calls its data with this loop:

```
for item in data['objects']:
     print item['name'], item['phone']
```

This works great for data stored as nested dictionaries (the outside being called objects, and the inside containing the data)

The issue I am having is my data is formatted with dictonaries inside of lists

```
[
{
"key":"2014cama",
"website":"http://www.cvrobotics.org/frc/regional.html",
"official":true,
"end_date":"2014-03-09",
"name":"Central Valley Regional",
"short_name":"Central Valley",
"facebook_eid":null,
"event_district_string":null,
"venue_address":"Madera South High School\n705 W. Pecan Avenue\nMadera, CA 93637\nUSA",      
 "event_district":0,
"location":"Madera, CA, USA",
"event_code":"cama",
"year":2014,
"webcast":[],
"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
"alliances":[],
"event_type_string":"Regional",
"start_date":"2014-03-07",
"event_type":0
},'more data...']
```

so calling,

```
for item in data['objects']:
     print item['name']
```

Won't work to pull the value stored in `name`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The full Dataset I'm pulling (http://www.thebluealliance.com/api/v2/team/frc254/2014/events?X-TBA-App-Id=Peter_Hartnett:Scouting:v1)

And the code I am running:

```
import json,urllib2, TBA

team ='frc254'
year = '2014'



Url = 'http://www.thebluealliance.com/api/v2/team/'+team+'/'+year+'/events?X-                        TBA-App-Id=Peter_Hartnett:Scouting:v1'
data = TBA.GetData(Url)

for item in data:
     print item['name']
```

The TBA Class just imports the data and returns it.

Edit2:
Here is the TBA class that pulls the data, I can assure you it is identical to that found at the link above

```
import urllib2,cookielib
content='none'


def GetData(Url):
    site= Url
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': '    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.fp.read()

    content = page.read()
    return content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, your `data['objects']` is now an entry in a list, right?

So just iterate the list and your logic will remain the same

```
for item in objects:
     print item['name'], item['phone']
```

being

```
objects = [
{
"key":"2014cama",
"website":"http://www.cvrobotics.org/frc/regional.html",
"official":true,
"end_date":"2014-03-09",
"name":"Central Valley Regional",
"short_name":"Central Valley",
"facebook_eid":null,
"event_district_string":null,
"venue_address":"Madera South High School\n705 W. Pecan Avenue\nMadera, CA 93637\nUSA",      
 "event_district":0,
"location":"Madera, CA, USA",
"event_code":"cama",
"year":2014,
"webcast":[],
"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
"alliances":[],
"event_type_string":"Regional",
"start_date":"2014-03-07",
"event_type":0
},'more data...']
```

#### Edit

I get your problem now. Your object `data` is a `string` that represents a `JSONArray` . You should ***load*** that before iterating, in order to be able to work with that as a real `list`, like so:

```
data = GetData(Url)

loaded_array = json.loads(data)

for item in loaded_array:
     print item['name']
```

Comment: your assumption is correct, however when I run that I recieve the error:    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @PeterHartnett It shouldnt happen. Are you sure your data structures are as in your example? What command raises this error? Please check if your `objects` variable is a list, and `item` is a `dict` as I wrote above ! :)

Comment: I have added my raw code to the initial post and the link to the data I'm pulling from.

Comment: @PeterHartnett could you post the `data` and `type(data)` ?

Comment: I have added the code for the class that pulls the data, it cant use a traditional urllib2.load because the API requires parameters to be passed in. This will return exactly the same data seen at the link also in the inital post.

Comment: @PeterHartnett I have edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much! consider this your good deed for the day! Helped a mentor-less kid learn to program, straight out of a halmark card :)

Comment: @PeterHartnett I am really glad I could help :)